# Perl hash to oauth signature

Tags: perl, hash, oauth

I found an example of how to make an oauth signature, but having a problem with a multidimensional hash. My hash looks like this using Data::Dumper to display my hash called %request:

```
$VAR1 = { 'Invoice' => { 'Line' => [ { 'Id' => '1', 'SalesItemLineDetail' => { 'ItemRef' => { 'value' => 'SKM2267' }, 'UnitPrice' => '10.00' }, 'DetailType' => 'SalesItemLineDetail', 'LineNum' => 1 }, { 'Id' => '2', 'SalesItemLineDetail' => { 'ItemRef' => { 'value' => 'SKM2292' }, 'UnitPrice' => '20.00' }, 'DetailType' => 'SalesItemLineDetail', 'LineNum' => 2 }, { 'Id' => '3', 'SalesItemLineDetail' => { 'ItemRef' => { 'value' => 'SKM2285' }, 'UnitPrice' => '30.00' }, 'DetailType' => 'SalesItemLineDetail', 'LineNum' => 3 } ], 'DocNumber' => '90210', 'CustomerRef' => \{ 'name' => 'Amazon.com', 'value' => 1 } } };
```

The example to make the signature involves joining the %request hash above into a string:

```
my $string = join('&',map {$_ . '=' . uri_escape($request{$_})} sort keys %request);
```

But this produces the following which is not consistent to be used as a signature:

```
Invoice=HASH%280x7f254c17b540%29
```

How can I handle this hash to create the string I need to pass into my oauth signature string?

The example script, which works fine, uses the following to construct the oauth signature:

```
my $hmac = Digest::HMAC_SHA1->new($e->{params}{qbo_consumer_secret} . '&' . $e->{params}{qbo_access_token_secret});
$hmac->add('GET&' . uri_escape('https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/' . $company_id . '/query') . '&' . uri_escape('oauth_consumer_key=' . $consumer_key . '&oauth_nonce=' . $nonce . '&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=' . $time . '&oauth_token=' . $access_token . '&oauth_version=1.0' . '&' . join('&',map {$_ . '=' . uri_escape($params{$_})} sort keys %params)));
```

As compared to what I am trying:

```
my $hmac = Digest::HMAC_SHA1->new($e->{params}{qbo_consumer_secret} . '&' . $e->{params}{qbo_access_token_secret});
$hmac->add('POST&' . uri_escape($server) . '&' . uri_escape('oauth_consumer_key=' . $e->{params}{qbo_consumer_key}) . '&oauth_nonce=' . $nonce . '&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=' . $time . '&oauth_token=' . $e->{params}{qbo_access_token} . '&oauth_version=1.0' . '&' . join('&',map {$_ . '=' . uri_escape($request{$_})} sort keys %request));
```

Then the request includes this authorization header:

```
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $server);
$req->header(Authorization =>
    'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="' . $e->{qbo_consumer_key}
    . '",oauth_nonce="' . $nonce
    . '",oauth_signature="' . encode_base64($hmac->digest)
    . '",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1'
    . '",oauth_timestamp="' . time();
    . '",oauth_token="' . $e->{qbo_access_token}
    . '",oauth_version="1.0'
    . '"');
$req->content( \%request );
```

Also, trying to convert the hash to json results in 'cannot encode reference to scalar'. I try this simple test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;

my %hash = { 'Invoice' => { 'Line' => [ { 'Id' => '1', 'SalesItemLineDetail' => { 'ItemRef' => { 'value' => 'SKM2267' }, 'UnitPrice' => '10.00' }, 'DetailType' => 'SalesItemLineDetail', 'LineNum' => 1 }, { 'Id' => '2', 'SalesItemLineDetail' => { 'ItemRef' => { 'value' => 'SKM2292' }, 'UnitPrice' => '20.00' }, 'DetailType' => 'SalesItemLineDetail', 'LineNum' => 2 }, { 'Id' => '3', 'SalesItemLineDetail' => { 'ItemRef' => { 'value' => 'SKM2285' }, 'UnitPrice' => '30.00' }, 'DetailType' => 'SalesItemLineDetail', 'LineNum' => 3 } ], 'DocNumber' => '90210', 'CustomerRef' => \{ 'name' => 'Amazon.com', 'value' => 1 } } };

my $js = encode_json \%hash;
print "$js\n";
```

Produces this error below, is there something wrong with my hash?

```
Reference found where even-sized list expected at testjson.pl line 8.
{"HASH(0x8db5f3c)":null}
```

Comment: What precisely are you trying to `uri_escape`?  `$request{$_}` is a hash reference and not generally the kind of thing you want to stringify.

Comment: Yeah, guess I don't need the uri_escape, the example I was following uses the HMAC packages add function to construct the signature for a GET request, but I'm using POST for this particular Quickbooks API call. Confusing to me as well how a string could be produced, but from what I understand the request has to be part of the oauth signature. I'll add the example that works compared to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: In the working example the signature is being constructed from the elements that make up the HTTP request - method, host and query string. How are you using `%request` to build `$req`?

Comment: Yes, as the content, I've added above. I am not having any luck converting the hash to a json string either using the JSON package. Doesn't give me the entire hash using $json->encode(%request);.

Answer (score 0):

So firstly, if you read the JSON module docs, it quite clearly states that the `encode` method only takes a scalar so passing it a hash won't work. When you pass a hash like that to a function, it takes each key and value and passes them separately.

```
my %hash=("a" => 1,"b" => 2);
my_func(%hash);
# The above function call is the same as the one below
my_func("b",2,"a",1);
```

the order it passes each key/value pairing is random as you'd normally find with a hash. It should even throw up an error telling you how to use it or at least the version I've got installed did when I tried testing out your code.

Instead what you actually want to do is pass in the hashref like this

```
$json->encode(\%request);
```

The value that returns is what you need to pass to `$req->content()` and use in the signature. I don't know anything of the Quickbooks API to know if you are meant to pass the JSON data as is or use it as a value to a CGI parameter though. It should be something it tells you in their documentation I would hope.

Comment: Actually I have tried my $js = $json->encode(\%request); and get the this error: cannot encode reference to scalar. I'll add more above.

Comment: @rwfitzy you're creating your hash incorrectly - the outermost hash is created with brackets not braces. See my answer for an example of how to create a hash. The inner ones are done with braces though